# Driver problems with Linux kernel upgrade from 5.3.0-28-generic x86_64 to 5.3.0.40

Tags: drivers, upgrade, kernel, lts

I'm using a Asus Vivobook (bought 2014) with Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver) 64-bit with the Linux Kernel 5.3.0-28-generic x86_64 and Ubuntu offers me to upgrade the Linux kernel 5.3.0.40.
The upgrade works well, i can boot the new version, it has an entry in the GRUB manager etc. BUT after the upgrade i can't connect to the internet (neither with wifi/wlan nor lan), there isn't any sound and Ubuntu won't recognize any external display, that is connected via HDMI. I'm  sure the upgrade killed the drivers, because i couldn't find any. I also deinstalled my antivirus to exclude a possible error source and did the upgrade again, but the problem is the same.
Edit: Since then i use the old kernel (5.3.0-28). Thanks to Nmath for reminding me to mention that.
Therefore my question: What went wrong ? Is there a bug, or some obsure config or is my hardware not longer supported ?
If anyone asks: i searched the web since march 2020, but didn't found a solution for my problem.

Comment: You have some options.  First, boot into the old kernel from GRUB options and see if the problem is *really* about the kernel.  Second, *update your system*.  Maybe the problem is fixed in a more recent kernel version. If you haven't updated since March you are seven months behind on updates. You should not go more than a month without updates

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot  to add, that I'm using the old kernel (5.3.0-28) since that event and everything works fine with the old version.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Got some issues with editing my post since I'm new to ask Ubuntu and didn't know about the one minute cooldown. Nevertheless, what i wanted to add:
"Just looked for an Kernel update. No update for the Linux kernel is available(on 5.3.0-28), but an Update for the Ubuntu kernel.
Gonna make that update and report the result."
I did it on the same day and some magic happened:After the update 5.3.0.40 worked fine with all drivers that were previously missing. The old versions 5.3.0.28 does not work since then.  Strange, but I'm happy that it worked somehow. Thanks Nmath